# The decryption correctness of RLWE based Encryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto

I get stuck in the proof of decryption correctness in RLWE based Cryptosystem. To state where I am , let me show the full scheme first. The image is from chapter 3.2 of [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/144.pdf).
[image]

**And the decryption correctness proof** of the scheme follows
[image]

In this proof , I can get the second last equation in decryption procedure , i.e.
$$\mathbf{m} + (t/q)(\mathbf{v}-\epsilon \cdot \mathbf{m}) + t\cdot \mathbf{r} $$

But for the last equation I don't know why.
$$(t/q)||\mathbf{v}-\epsilon \cdot \mathbf{m}|| \lt 1/2 $$

I hava some clues. We already have $||\mathbf{v}|| \le 2\cdot \delta_R \cdot B^2 + B$, then for $2\cdot \delta_R \cdot B^2 + B \lt \Delta / 2$, we have $||\mathbf{v}|| \lt \frac{q}{2t}$ since $\Delta = \lfloor q/t \rfloor \le q/t$. Hence $(t/q)||\mathbf{v}|| \lt \frac{1}{2}$. This is very similar to what we want ,i.e. $(t/q)||\mathbf{v}-\epsilon \cdot \mathbf{m}|| \lt 1/2 $.
I guess there is a relation between $||\mathbf{v}||$ and $||\mathbf{v}-\epsilon \cdot \mathbf{m}||$ , but I don't know how to build the relation between them. The proof in the paper have a short explanation "Since $\mathbf{m} \in R_t$" , but I can not understand. Anyone gives some hint would be helpful.

Plus, the norm in this paper in infinity norm.

**Edit20220601:**
Add some explanation above.

1. $\delta_R $ is called the expansion factor of a ring $R$. And $\delta_R = \max{\frac{||a\cdot b||}{||a||\cdot ||b||}},a\in R, b\in R$.
2. In the above, we have $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{e}\cdot \mathbf{u}+ \mathbf{e}_1 +\mathbf{e}_2\cdot \mathbf{s}$, since $\mathbf{e},\mathbf{u},\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{s} \in \chi$,so their infinity norm all have bound $B$, then $||\mathbf{e}\cdot \mathbf{u}||= \frac{||\mathbf{e}\cdot \mathbf{u}||}{||\mathbf{e}||\cdot ||\mathbf{u}||}\cdot ||\mathbf{e}||\cdot ||\mathbf{u}|| \le \delta_R \cdot B^2$,similarly, $||\mathbf{e}_2 \cdot \mathbf{s}|| \le \delta_R \cdot B^2$, so we have $||\mathbf{v}|| \le 2\cdot \delta_R \cdot B^2 + B$

Comment: [Cross-posting is not a good ethic in SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Could you delete the math copy?

Comment: @kelalaka Sorry, didn't realize that. Will delete it right now.

Comment: Is there any assumed relationship between $t$ and $q$? It is straightforward to get the bound $(t/q)\lVert \epsilon\vec m\rVert_\infty \leq t^2/2q$. With a strong enough assumption on $t, q$, this suffices to nearly get your bound (you will lose some constant factor which should be able to be ignored in this setting).

Comment: There is no talk about the relationship betwenn $t$ and $q$ in the preliminary of the paper . But in a homomorphic library like SEAL, tipically we have parameters like $t$ is $4096$ and $q$ is a number of size $109$ bits. $(t/q)||\mathbf{v} -\epsilon \cdot \mathbf{m}|| \le (t/q)(||\mathbf{v}||+\epsilon||\mathbf{m}|| ) \le (t/q)(\Delta/2)+ (t/q)(\epsilon \cdot (t/2)) \le (t/q)\cdot (q/2t)+(t/q)(\epsilon \cdot (t/2) ) = 1/2 + \frac{\epsilon \cdot t^2}{2q}$

Comment: @Mark In the parameter setting ,  $\frac{\epsilon \cdot t^2}{2q}$ is small , maybe negligible, but still I can't make it strictly less than $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I don't have time to look through the paper now, but it is perhaps worth mentioning that if $t\mid q$, it is straightforward to show that $\epsilon =0$, and this whole problem goes away. This is the most common setting (both practically and theoretically), although it does not resolve your question fully.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I got stuck in this proof and didn't continue read the following paper, it seems the parameters make things different so much.